# What's the easiest way to setup Visual Studio for normal C++ development (non .net)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, portability

I want to code the most portable C++ possible using Visual Studios. There is no option for a C++ project that isn't Visual. What settings do I change so the compiler catches anything that wouldn't be considered standard C++?

It's really annoying because whenever I create a new project instead of creating a `main` function, it creates `_tmain` which won't work on another platform.

Comment: Use [qtcreator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/category:tools::qtcreator), you can easily create cross-platform gui apps in C++ or just use plain c++ without qt.

Comment: Is this visual or console? If its console, just create a visual template and select console.

Comment: @Robert it's console

Comment: For console mode, create project, win32 console, and choose empty project (it's just after you click on "next". Then click on project, add existing item, and click on your source file (C or C++). You can also right click on the project name, properties, character set, and choose "not set" if you don't want unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> What settings do I change so the compiler catches anything that wouldn't be considered standard C++?

The `/Za` compiler switch disables Microsoft-specific extensions.  It won't make the compiler 100% standard-compliant, but it will flag most non-portable code.

As to fixing the new project 
wizard, you can make your own project template, but making a code snippet with the standard signature is a lot less work.

Answer (score 0):

Create your project, and let it create the Unicode abomination called _tmain().  Then rename it to main(), and change the type of argv to char **.

Finally go to your project settings and in "Configuration Properties" -> "General" change the "Character Set" to "Not Set".  That'll switch it back to ASCII, at which point you are now about as portable as you can be.

If you *really* want to check for portability, you can download VirtualBox, use it to set up a VM with a Linux distribution on it (I use Ubuntu LTS at work for this), and ensure that you can compile and run on both platforms.  It's a bit of work to set up, but well worth it in the long run, since it allows you to be sure the project is completely cross platform.